# Dynatable and input fields (like checkboxes)

Tags: jquery, checkbox, pagination, dynatable

I'm not so skilled in jQuery, so I downloaded Dynatable to manipulate my tables.

It's OK for almost all features, but I don't know how to keep the state of the input fields when I use the pagination.

For instance: the first column of each row of my table is a checkbox. So I check some checkboxes in the first page, then I change the page, then a go back to the first page and the checkboxes are unchecked because the script rebuild the table each time I suppose.

How can I solve this?

Comment: in order to help us help you, please post all code relevant to your question

Comment: JavaScript and HTML is stateless. If you want to retain state changes across HTTP requests you need to persist them to localstorage, cookies, a database etc.

Comment: How do we know why your checkboxes change? You haven't posted a single bit of code. If it's so urgent why is ther no code and no demo to replicate your situation? Don't post that things are `urgent` .. it won't get you any more attention than any other question here

Comment: I understand your urgency...dear you have to post the relevant code or similar code to help us understanding where the problem is. On a high level, I can assure you will have to maintain the checked checkboxes in an array pageviz...and then check them again on page change. As far as I understand this feature is not directly supported in dynatable and need to be handled manually in code.

Comment: I don't post any code because I don't know which kind of code I should post. I'm talking about a situation I don't know at all, not a situation within my code don't work. So I'm not asking why my code don't work, because I haven't a code yet. I have just the normal example code of dynatalbe (a plugin for jquery). Maybe, every time I change the page of the pagination, I have to store all the new values in the table, so I could have a new map of the entire table, but I don't know much of jquery, so someone coul post for me some code please. If is it possible?